# SwiftUI getby UUID

Tags: ios, swiftui, uuid

I'm pretty new to SwiftUI so I'm hoping someone can help me out here.
I have a UUID and I am trying to save content into that specific object, but I do not know how to call the object, like with a getbyid or something.

```
struct Game: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: UUID
    var title: String
    var players: [Player]
}
extension Game {
    struct Player: Identifiable, Codable {
        let id: UUID
        var name: String
        var score: [Int32]
    }
}
```

used this code in my program

```
@Binding var game: Game
saveScoreToPlayer(game: $game, playerID: player.id, score: Int32)

func saveScoreToPlayer(game: Game, playerID: Game.Player.ID, score: Int32) {
    //save score to player obviously doesn't work
    game.playerID.insert(score at:0)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `firstIndex(of:)` method to get the position of the first element of the array that matches `playerID`.

You can try this:

```
func saveScoreToPlayer(game: Game, playerID: Game.Player.ID, score: Int32) {
    if let index = game.players.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == playerID }) {
        game.players[index].score.insert(score, at: 0)
    } else {
        // handle error here
    }
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994720-firstindex)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few of ways you can do this. None is necessarily advantageous, although the second one (with the `map`) may prove slower in situations with huge data sets.

Note that in the examples I changed the function to accept `Binding<Game>` since that's what you are passing in in your call site.

```
func saveScoreToPlayer(game: Binding<Game>, playerID: Game.Player.ID, score: Int32) {
    guard let index = game.wrappedValue.players.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == playerID }) else {
        fatalError()
    }
    game.wrappedValue.players[index].score.append(score)
}
```

or

```
func saveScoreToPlayer(game: Binding<Game>, playerID: Game.Player.ID, score: Int32) {
    game.wrappedValue.players = game.wrappedValue.players.map {
        guard $0.id == playerID else { return $0 }
        var copy = $0
        copy.score.append(score)
        return copy
    }
}
```

or:

```
func saveScoreToPlayer3(game: Binding<Game>, playerID: Game.Player.ID, score: Int32) {
    guard let player = game.players.first(where: { $0.id == playerID
    }) else {
        fatalError()
    }
    player.wrappedValue.score.append(score)
}
```